# Conexão Flask entre duas Máquinas

Tags: python, rest, flask

Tenho uma aplicação Cliente-Servidor em Flask, executando os dois arquivos na mesma máquina a conexão funciona perfeitamente, mas quando tento executar o cliente em uma máquina diferente, a conexão não é estabelecida. Eu coloco o IP da máquina servidora no arquivo cliente mas não tenho sucesso. Alguém tem ideia do que fazer?

Servidor:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

todos = {}

valores = {}

contador = 0

class TodoSimple(Resource):

    def get(self, todo_id):
        #return {todo_id: todos[todo_id]}

        return valores[todo_id]

    def put(self, todo_id):
        global contador, valores
        contador+=1

        #print(contador)

        todos[todo_id] = request.form['data']

        if contador==4:
            contador = 0
            valores['CPF'] = todos['CPF']
            valores['Latitude'] = todos['Latitude']
            valores['Longitude'] = todos['Longitude']
            valores['Velocidade'] = todos['Velocidade']


        return {todo_id: todos[todo_id]}

api.add_resource(TodoSimple, '/<string:todo_id>')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=False)
```

Cliente:

```
from requests import put

put('http://localhost:5000/CPF', data={'data': '12345678910'}).json()
put('http://localhost:5000/Latitude', data={'data': '-3.10'}).json()
put('http://localhost:5000/Longitude', data={'data': '-20.4000'}).json()
put('http://localhost:5000/Velocidade', data={'data': '60.5'}).json()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documentado no site Flask em "Servidor Externamente Visível" na página [Quickstart](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#a-minimal-application) ( em Inglês ).

> Servidor Externamente Visível
>
> Se você executar o servidor, notará que o servidor só está disponível
>   no seu próprio computador e não em nenhum outro da rede. Este é o
>   padrão porque, no modo de depuração, um usuário do aplicativo pode
>   executar o código Python arbitrário em seu computador. Se você tiver
>   desabilitado debug ou confiar nos usuários em sua rede, você pode
>   disponibilizar o servidor publicamente.
>
> Basta alterar a chamada do método run () para se parecer com isto:
>
> app.run (host = '0.0.0.0')
>
> Isso indica ao seu sistema operacional que escute em um IP público.

Servidor:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=False)
```

Cliente:

```
put('http://0.0.0.0:5000/CPF', data={'data': '12345678910'}).json()
put('http://0.0.0.0:5000/Latitude', data={'data': '-3.10'}).json()
put('http://0.0.0.0:5000/Longitude', data={'data': '-20.4000'}).json()
put('http://0.0.0.0:5000/Velocidade', data={'data': '60.5'}).json()
```

Altere `0.0.0.0` pelo endereço de `IP` do servidor, altere no cliente `localhost` pelo `IP` do servidor.

Após configurar e ainda não conseguir ter acesso, verifique também se o `firewall` não está bloqueando a porta `5000`.